# create table with jquery. wrong order of code execution?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

i've got another problem with my jquery code.
Here some example code:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input.goto_batterie_pruefung', function() {
   /** some code**/
    $.ajax({
        url: "example.php",
        type: "post",
        data: /* some data */,
        datatype: "json",
        success: function(data) {

            var data=$.parseJSON(data);

            $('#div_testausgabe').html('');
            $('#div_testausgabe').append('<hr /><table><thead><tr><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr></thead><tbody>');

            $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                  /* some variables for tabledata */

                $('#div_testausgabe').append('<tr>');
                var text='<td>'+data+'</td><td>'+data+'</td><td>'+data+'</td><td>'+data+'</td><td>'+data+'</td><td>'+data+'</td><td>'+data+'</td>';
                $('#div_testausgabe').append(text);
                $('#div_testausgabe').append('</tr>');
            });

            $('#div_testausgabe').append('</tbody></table><hr />');

        }
    });
});
```

My problem is that the table doesn't get created correctly. the table tags will surround only the thead part.

Comment: Is this your actual code? Try first by changing the comment block to actual code. Change `/* some variables for tabledata *"` probably to `/* some variables for tabledata */`

Comment: Is the code you're using actually commented out like that? Or did you do that just for the question?

Comment: Your use of append is wrong: `.append('</tr>');` Append() doesn't write string to document but append element. What about reading the DOC?

Comment: i just commented all the variables out for this question. but the variables shouldn't be the problem, they get loaded correct between the td elements

Comment: When you use `.append()` you are supposed to be appending *complete* DOM nodes.  `$('#div_testausgabe').append('<tr>');` doesn't do what you think.  This will append a `<tr>` tag, not just the opening tag as you think.  You need to build the HTML first, then append the whole string.  `.append()` is not the same as appending to a string you don't append the opening tag, the data, and then the closing tag.  You call `.append()` with the *entire* HTML string.

Comment: You are not using the close table tag, please, create a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can better help you get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You're definitely building the table wrong. `.append()` is going to be appending to your `<div id="div_testausgabe">`, so you end up with

```
<div> id="div_testausgabe">
   <hr /><table><thead> blah blah blah from your first .append call</table>
   <tr><td>row #1 from the .each() call></tr></td>
   <tr><td>row #2 from the .each() call()</tr></td>
   etc...
</div>
```

You need to isolate the actual table inside your div, e.g.

```
$('#div_testausgabe table tbody').append(....);
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

so that your new tr/td nodes are going into the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

Don't append partial html, you will be updating the DOM a lot of times, making it slower and causing multiple redraws and the browser will try to correct it.

You should build a string of html and append that at the end, after the `$.each()` loop.

Something like:

```
$('#div_testausgabe').html('');
var table_html = '<hr /><table><thead><tr><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr></thead><tbody>';

$.each(data, function(index, value) {
    table_html += '<tr><td>'+data+'</td><td>'+data+'</td><td>'+data+'</td><td>'+data+'</td><td>'+data+'</td><td>'+data+'</td><td>'+data+'</td></tr>';
});

table_html += '</tbody></table><hr />';
$('#div_testausgabe').append(table_html);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery's append() as if it was a string concatenation, which it isn't.